# How to make the Eclipse code template like this?

Tags: java, eclipse

In some Eclipse project, I can see the every code file(.java) has a code template like this:

```
public class AClass {
  // ===========================================================
  // Constants
  // ===========================================================

  // ===========================================================
  // Fields
  // ===========================================================

  // ===========================================================
  // Constructors
  // ===========================================================
  // ===========================================================
  // Getter & Setter
  // ===========================================================

  // ===========================================================
  // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
  // ===========================================================

  // ===========================================================
  // Methods
  // ===========================================================

  // ===========================================================
  // Inner and Anonymous Classes
  // ===========================================================
}
```

I want to generate these comments automatically when create a new java class, so how do I do?

I try to set the code templates in Eclipse preferences, but didn't success.

Comment: How do you put Anonymous classes in their own section?  Aren't anonymous classes defined inline?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to go to the Eclipse Preferences, to the Java/Code Style/Code Template and choose for example New Java File or Class body, and edit it!

Comment: In the Code templates I change the Comments/Getter and apply it for test. but the Getter's context was changed but the comment of getter didn't generate automatically. I selected the "Generate comments" in crate class dialogue.

Comment: It's just auto generate the Comments/Types above the class name.

Comment: I misunderstand you, now I find the "New Java File or Class body" I just add these comments in the class body. Thank you very much :)